# Does bonus damage stack?

Tags: bravely-default

Monsters can have multiple weak points due to elemental weaknesses and what monster family they belong to. When you exploit these weaknesses, a prompt appears that says "Weak Point!" and you deal bonus damage (usually an increased 50%). However, does this 50% increase in damage stack when you hit multiple weak points with a single attack or stack multiple sources of bonus damage on one weakness?

For the first case, consider a Beast monster with a weakness to Fire. If I use Sword Magic: Fire, would I do more damage if I used an anti-Beast weapon as opposed to normal weapon of equal stats? In the second case, would I do even more damage if I attacked a flying enemy with a bow (which fliers are innately weak to) while using Aerial Slayer (Ranger skill)?

Comment: Since Ranger are made for being archer, and since they are given a attack speccially to fight Aerial, I think bonus stack, but it would require testing.

Comment: Not quite true as Rangers also have S-rank aptitude with daggers/knives.

Comment: Nice point, but that would mean that Aerial Slayer would be a useless attack if used with a bow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Elemental Weakness effect and monster type effects stack. I tested it with a anti-beast fire attack.